# Including a JSP file from a Java EE Filter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jetty, servlet-filters

I am trying to include a JSP page after the end of a filter. I have the following code:

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {            
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        finally {                                
                HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = httpRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/logging/logAppender.jsp");
                dispatcher.include(request, response); // This does not work!
                dispatcher.include(request, response); // The second time it works?                
        }
    }
```

Pretty simple Filter I think. However, as you can see above, for some reason calling include the first time doesn't do anything. I am just confused and tired of debugging. I have tried calling .flushBuffer(), getWriter().flush(), all kinds of close() and still don't understand. Any ideas would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many unknowns and a lot of things that can only be figured out through debugging for me to give any kind of answer.  A good resource that may help you is Marty Hall's Moreservlets book.  You can read it for free at http://pdf.moreservlets.com/.  Read chapter 9 on Filters.

Comment: I will try to create a dead simple java application to see if the same as above happens. If it doesn't then there must be something special about this app. Otherwise, there must be something else going on. I thought perhaps at the end of the chain, the response has been already committed so it doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Probably it is because you are passing the wrapped request and response to the request dispatcher, try passing the by a cast to `HttpServletResponse` and `HttpServletRequest`

```
 dispatcher.include((HttpServletRequest) request, (HttpServletResponse)response)
```

Comment: This is not true. Casting doesn't change/copy the concrete instance or something. Java is OO.